# ionic side menu routing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new using ionic but I can't make routing correctly

I started using a side menu project, when I tried routing my login page to the main page where the side menu is, the button from the side menu dissapear

I have the next code for routing

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

  .state('menu.maps', {
url: '/page1',
views: {
  'side-menu21': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/maps.html',
    controller: 'mapaCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('menu', {
url: '/side-menu21',
templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
controller: 'menuCtrl'
})

  .state('login', {
url: '/page10',
templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
controller: 'loginCtrl'
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/side-menu21/page1')

});
```

How can I route the login page to the maps page with the side menu

Comment: You said "the button from the side menu dissapear" , so you are getting side menu but content of menu is not showing ?

Comment: When the route is directing to menu.maps I can see the side menu, but when when I try to acces to menu.maps from the login page the menu side menu button dissapear, that's why I can't acces to the side menu